# matching row values by group (r, data.table)

Tags: r, data.table, match

I apologise if this might seems a too abstract.
I'm facing this issue. I some data like that:

```
dt<-data.table(time=rep("3",5),record=c(1,2,3,4,4),type=c("A","B","B","A","A"),movement=c("Z","D","Z","Z","D"))
```

My goal here is to flag types B against types A, based on `record` and `movement`.

```
     time record type movement
1:    3      1    A        Z
2:    3      2    B        D
3:    3      3    B        Z
4:    3      4    A        Z
5:    3      4    A        D
```

The logic is the following: we can see that type B, record 2, has a D movement. We see that the D movement is contained only in type A movements of record 4, but not in type A movements of record 1 (which only has the Z movement). In that case, I need to flag that B type record with 1. The other B type record has movement Z, that is contained in both records 1 and 4. In that case, I will flag it with a 0, like in the following.

```
    time record type movement flag
1:    3      1    A        Z   
2:    3      2    B        D   1
3:    3      3    B        Z   0
4:    3      4    A        Z  
5:    3      4    A        D
```

I couldn't really work my head around how to solve this in a simple way. Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: This seems like maybe a task for a graph data structure (supported in R by the igraph package and maybe others). You could have a bipartite graph with A nodes/records on one side and B on the other, creating links between them based on a condition like "this B node's movement is not found among this A node's". Some examples if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bigraph%5d%20bipartite%20is%3aQ

Comment: Can you be more specific about the rules? Do you want to set the B `flag` to `1` every time a B movement is encountered that isn't present in *every* A record ? Or just in the preceding ones?

Comment: @Esther I think the explanation makes it more difficult than it actually is. I am matching A and B types. We see that D movement from record 2 (B type) is only present in record 4 (A type). In that case, I flag it with 1. movement Z from record 3 (B type) is present in both types A records, therefore I flag it with a 0. What this means in English is that I can unambiguously trace back type B movement D to a specific type A record, but I can't do the same with movement Z (it's present in both types A). I know, it's kind of confused, but it's a real problem I'm trying to solve

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think the point about unambiguous vs ambiguous matches is helpful and I would edit it into your question. I have provided an answer, but if you have other types of conditions (for example do you want to treat 'no matches' the same as 'multiple matches'?) I would add them into your question and I can revise accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is flag unambigous record matches from B to A, this will work

```
library(data.table)

dt<-data.table(time=rep("3",5),record=c(1,2,3,4,4),type=c("A","B","B","A","A"),movement=c("Z","D","Z","Z","D"))

#group the A records
mat<-as.matrix(table(dt[type=="A",record], dt[type=="A",movement]))

#select which ones are unambiguous
unambiguous<-names(which(colSums(mat)==1))

#check them against the B records
dt[,flag:=ifelse(dt[,type]=="B" & dt[,movement] %in% unambiguous, 1, NA)]

dt[,flag:=ifelse(dt[,type]=="B" & !dt[,movement] %in% unambiguous, 0, dt[,flag])]

dt

#    time record type movement flag
# 1:    3      1    A        Z   NA
# 2:    3      2    B        D    1
# 3:    3      3    B        Z    0
# 4:    3      4    A        Z   NA
# 5:    3      4    A        D   NA
```

But if you have other kinds of cases I think we would need more information.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It does work, even though it is not scalable to the original dataset (but that's my fault). But you surely gave me some ideas on how to tackle the issue.

Comment: Can you describe why it's not scalable? Like I said I'm happy to update the answer if you can provide more information

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
dt <- data.table(time=rep("3",5),
                 record=c(1,2,3,4,4),
                 type=c("A","B","B","A","A"),
                 movement=c("Z","D","Z","Z","D"))

# Count number of records by type and movement
grp.type_movement <- dt %>% group_by(type, movement)
dt.type_movement <- grp.type_movement %>% summarize( n=n() )

# Add the flag variable to input dataset
dt_with_flag <- merge( dt.type_movement %>% filter( type == "A"),
                       dt.type_movement %>% filter( type == "B" ),
                       by="movement", suffixes=c(".A", ".B") ) %>%
                  # Find A types with count = 1 and assign flag variable accordingly
                  mutate( flag=if_else( n.A == 1, 1, 0) ) %>%
                  # Select relevant variables for final merge with original dataset
                  select( type=type.B, movement, flag ) %>%
                  # Right merge with original dataset
                  merge( dt, by=c("type", "movement"), all.y=TRUE ) %>%
                  # Re-sort by record
                  arrange( record ) %>%
                  # Re-arrange the columns in the final dataset to their original order 
                  select( time, record, type, movement, flag)
```

Note that the result of the initial `merge` and `mutate` in the last command is:

```
  movement type.A n.A type.B n.B flag
1        D      A   1      B   1    1
2        Z      A   2      B   1    0
```

And the result of the final command (from begin to end) is:

```
  time record type movement flag
1    3      1    A        Z   NA
2    3      2    B        D    1
3    3      3    B        Z    0
4    3      4    A        D   NA
5    3      4    A        Z   NA
```

which is what you wished.

However I don't know if you will always have only two `type` values or whether you would like to generalize the process to more `type` values? If the latter is the case, what defines the asymmetry between the `type` values? (i.e. in your example `type B` doesn't play the same role as `type A`...